# How to print all lines of a file that do not contain a *partial* pattern

Tags: bash

We know grep -v pattern file prints lines that do not contain pattern.

My file to search is a table:

```
Sample File, Sample Name, Panel, Marker, Allele 1, Allele 2, GQ, 
M090972.s-206_B01.fsa, M090972-206, Sample ID-1, SNPchr1, C, T,0.9933,
```

I want to weed out the lines that contain "M090972-206" and some more patterns like that.

My search patterns come from a directory of text files:

```
$ ls 20170227_snap_genotypes_1_VCF

M070370-208_S1.genome.vcf   M170276-201_S20.genome.vcf
M170308-201_S5.genome.vcf
```

Only the part of these filenames up to the first "_" is in my table (or the first "." if I remove the ".s" in the example). It *is not* a constant number of characters. I could remove the characters after the first "." but could not find a way in the sed and awk documentation.

Alternatively I tried using agrep 3.441 with the "-f" option for reading the patterns from a temporary file made with

```
$ ls "directory" > temp.txt
$ ./agrep -v -f temp.txt $infile >> $outfile
```

But `agrep -f` does not find any match (or everything with `-v`).
What am I missing? Is there a better way, perhaps with `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What is in temp.txt? Do you want to exclude all patterns contained in those vcf files or you want to derive the patterns from the file names?  Please quote your command sections by clicking on `{}` button on the edit window.

Comment: Tmp.txt is a file containing my search patterns. I want to exclude all lines of the vcf file that contain one of the search patterns and keep the ones that don't.

Comment: Is "directory" in `ls "directory"` `20170227_snap_genotypes_1_VCF`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are deriving your patterns from the name of files (up to the first `_`) that exist in `20170227_snap_genotypes_1_VCF` directory, then you could do this:

```
# run from the parent of 20170227_snap_genotypes_1_VCF directory
grep -vf <(cd 20170227_snap_genotypes_1_VCF; ls | cut -f1 -d_) file
```

Comment: I tried this with some real data and it works perfectly. Thank you! So, `grep -f` accepts output from another command, here `cut`. I read the `grep` man as this coming from a file name.